# How to print mathematical objects in text mode in lualatex?

Tags: luatex

In one of the callbacks of lualatex in lua (build_filter) I print the first argument of the function.

```
\begin{luacode}
function f(a)
tex.print(a)
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback("buildpage_filter",f,"build_filter")
\end{luacode}
```

But during compiling I get an error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
```

Ok, I know that the variable `a` probably has characters used in math mode, but how can I print it in text mode?

Comment: printing text from the `buildpage_filter` isn't really expected, I tried to extend your document to a test file but could not get the error that you show as the text never appeared in the document. If you provide a test file someone can easily debug it.

Comment: @sheß why the edit? In general it's better to use a code block than a quote for showing error messages

Comment: Thank you very mutch. Catcode -2 help me solve my problem. 

Answer (score 2):

Please always provide a usable test file not a fragment.

`buildpage_filter` gets an argument one of a fixed list of strings, some of them , such as `after_output` include an underscore so if you insert that string into the document via `tex.print` then you will need to use a non default catcode table.

One possible signature of `tex.print` is

```
tex.print(<number> n, <string> s, ...)
```

where `n` is the number of the catcode table used to print the string `s`.  There are two special catcode tables which are identified by negative numbers:

- `n = -1`: Uses the currently active catcode regime
- `n = -2`: Uses the same catcodes as `\the\toks`, i.e. all characters have catcode 12, expect spaces which have catcode 10.

Comment: But what category i must use in sprint function (because,as i understoode,print function not allow me set catcode category) Or i must use some another way to change this table,to fix my error.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy -2 should work, but as I say I couldn't get any text printed here to appear, why adding text _to the page_ from this filter?

Comment: @HenriMenke actually I think the manual is wrong there, catcode12 except space is like `\string` not like `\the\toks` but -2 is what is needed anyway.